# Swift - Sort nested array based on a property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have a following up set

```
struct Section {
    let content: [Category]
    
    func sortForItem3() -> [Category]  {
      // Sorting function
    }
}

struct Category {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item {
    let value: String
}

let item1: Item = Item(value: "item1")
let item2: Item = Item(value: "item2")
let item3: Item = Item(value: "item3")
let item4: Item = Item(value: "item4")

let category1: Category = Category(items: [item1, item2])
let category2: Category = Category(items: [item3, item4])
let sectionContent: Section = Section(content:[category1, category2])
```

On printing this section content

```
print(sectionContent)

Section(content: 
[SwiftPlayground.Category(items: [SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item1"), SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item2")]), 
SwiftPlayground.Category(items: [SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item3"), SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item4")])]
)
```

I'm trying to write a sort condition where I need to search for an item whose value is "Item3" and then move that category to the top.

The expected behavior would be when I print the content:

```
print(sectionContent.sortForItem3())
```

The desired output is

```
 Section(content: 
[SwiftPlayground.Category(items: [SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item3"), SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item4")]), 
SwiftPlayground.Category(items: [SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item1"), SwiftPlayground.Item(value: "item2")])]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should conform Item to `Equatable`, second change your content properties from constant to variable. Declare your method as mutating and remove the returning object. Then you just need to find the first index where items contains item:

```
struct Category {
    let items: [Item]
}
```

---

```
struct Item: Equatable {
    let value: String
}
```

---

```
struct Section {
    var content: [Category]
    mutating func moveCategoryThatContainsItemToTop(_ item: Item)  {
        if let index = content.firstIndex(where: {$0.items.contains(item)}) {
            content.insert(content.remove(at: index), at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let item1 = Item(value: "item1")
let item2 = Item(value: "item2")
let item3 = Item(value: "item3")
let item4 = Item(value: "item4")

let category1 = Category(items: [item1, item2])
let category2 = Category(items: [item3, item4])
var section = Section(content: [category1, category2])
print(section.content)
section.moveCategoryThatContainsItemToTop(item3)
print(section.content)
```

---

This will print

> [Category(items: [Item(value: "item1"), Item(value: "item2")]),
> Category(items: [Item(value: "item3"), Item(value: "item4")])]
>
> [Category(items: [Item(value: "item3"), Item(value: "item4")]),
> Category(items: [Item(value: "item1"), Item(value: "item2")])]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a highly productive solution? then if business logic allows it is better to replace one of the arrays with a dictionary. Or do something like this:

```
var content: [Category]

for i = 0..<content.count {
  var isFound = false
  for item in content[i].items {
    if item.value = "item3" {
      let tmpContent = content[i]         
      content[i] = content[0]
      content[0] = tmpContent
      isFound = true
      break
  }
  if isFound { break }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? This is definetly not Swift

Comment: `for i = 0..<content.count { ` ??? `if item.value = "item3" {` ???

Comment: Besides the bad syntax, this will swap the first element with the one found instead of removing the element and inserting it at the top of the collection

Comment: There is also a missing closing curly bracket

Comment: btw instead of creating an `isFound` boolean there is a feature in Swift that is almost unknown called `"labelled breaks"`. just name your break whatever you want `end: for i in 0..<` and then you can break it from the inner loops `break end` https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html